# Product of integrals is a multiple integral?

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-integral

In the context of multivariate normal variable:

Let $X = (X_1 , \ldots , X_n )^T$ denote a vector of $n$ independent, standard normal random variables. Let $\bar{x} = (x_1 , \ldots , x_n )^T$ be a vector of real values. The joint cumulative distribution function for $X$ is given as follows, where $\bar{w} = (w_1 , \ldots , w_n )^T$

$$
\Pr(X \leq \bar{x}) =
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
\int_{w_i = - \infty}^{x_i} \exp \left(
\frac{- w_i^2}{2}
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_i
\right)
$$

$$
=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\int_{w_1 = - \infty}^{x_1}
\ldots
\int_{w_n = - \infty}^{x_n}
\exp \left(
\frac{- \bar{w}^T \bar{w}}{2}
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}w_n
$$

My question: How did we obtain the last multiple integral?

---

Edit: Here's a rewritten version without the dot product:

$$
=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\int_{w_1 = - \infty}^{x_1}
\ldots
\int_{w_n = - \infty}^{x_n}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \left( w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \ldots + w_n^2 \right)
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}w_n
$$

So how do we tackle this multiple integral to get the product above?

Comment: Evaluate the exponent of the last integral in terms of $w_i$.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually the hard part for me - is there any rule for evaluating such a multiple integral?

Comment: In the $n=2$ case, this is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{w_1=-\infty}^{x_1} e^{-w_1^2/2}dw_1\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{w_2=-\infty}^{x_2} e^{-w_2^2/2}dw_2=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^2 \int_{w_1=-\infty}^{x_1} \int_{w_2=-\infty}^{x_2} e^{-(w_1^2+w_2^2)/2}dw_1 dw_2.$$ But this is just [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I guess I found a way here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699045/fubinis-theorem-double-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answer (many thanks to @Semiclassical ):

Using Fubini's theorem, we can prove that for a product of two functions $f(x)$, $g(y)$

$$
\iint \limits _{X\times Y}f(x) g(y)\,{\text{d}}x\, \text{d}y =
\int_X f(x) \text{d}x \int_Y g(y) \text{d}y \\
$$

(Proof can be found for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/699699/682779 )

So we can rewrite the CDF (applying the above theorem on line 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \Pr(X \leq \bar{x}) = \\
&=
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
\int_{w_i = - \infty}^{x_i} \exp \left(
\frac{- w_i^2}{2}
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_i
\right) \\
&=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \left(
\int_{w_i = - \infty}^{x_i} \exp \left(
\frac{- w_i^2}{2}
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_i
\right) \\
&=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\int_{w_1 = - \infty}^{x_1}
\ldots
\int_{w_n = - \infty}^{x_n}
\exp \left(\frac{- w_1^2}{2}\right)
\exp \left(\frac{- w_2^2}{2}\right)
\cdots
\exp \left(\frac{- w_n^2}{2}\right)
\mathrm{d}w_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}w_n \\
&=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\int_{w_1 = - \infty}^{x_1}
\ldots
\int_{w_n = - \infty}^{x_n}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \left( w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \ldots + w_n^2 \right)
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}w_n \\
&=
\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \right)^n
\int_{w_1 = - \infty}^{x_1}
\ldots
\int_{w_n = - \infty}^{x_n}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \bar{w}^T \bar{w}
\right)
\mathrm{d}w_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}w_n
\end{aligned}
$$
which is what we wanted.